# create a for loop and add row to the df after each iteration

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to construct an empty df with the specific columns and create a loop that adds a row in every iteration

```r
type <- c("AAA","BBB","CCC")
price <-c(0.5, 0.7, 0.2)
fixed_cost1<- 500
fixed_cost <- 200
Quantity<-c(400,700)
Month <-c(1,2,3)

df<-as.data.frame(matrix(,ncol=6,nrow=0))
```

I want to create a for loop that produces the data frame below. I want to calculate the total cost for every "type" for a 3-month period and for different "quantities" .The calculation of Total cost is the `(price[i]*Quantity[i]+fixed_cost1+ fixed_cost2)* Month[i]` . The final `df` will be very big as the total cost calculation has to be done for every type, for all the months for the quantity 400 and then the same for all the months for the quantity 700. Thank you for your time

| type | price | fixed_cost1 | fixed_cost2 | Month | Quantity | Total_Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 0.5 | 500 | 200 | 1 | 400 | 900 |
| AAA | 0.5 | 500 | 200 | 2 | 400 | 1800 |
| AAA | 0.5 | 500 | 200 | 3 | 400 | 2700 |
| AAA | 0.5 | 500 | 200 | 1 | 700 | 1050 |
| AAA | 0.5 | 500 | 200 | 2 | 700 | 2100 |
| AAA | 0.5 | 500 | 200 | 3 | 700 | 3150 |
| BBB | 0.7 | 500 | 200 | 1 | 400 | 980 |
| ---- | --- | --- | --- | -- | --- | ---- |
| BBB | 0.7 | 500 | 200 | 3 | 700 | 1190 |

Comment: Before I even look at your expected output, realize that iteratively adding rows to a frame scales very poorly; if you're interested, read *"Circle 2: Growing Objects"* from [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Long-story-short, each row added copies the entire frame, so the more rows that are added, its space in memory (and time to copy it) is double what the frame normally should be. There are options, depending on the use ...

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, it is really a bad idea to try to add rows iteratively to a frame, succumbing to the second circle of [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (*Growing Objects*). But I think we can build this *all at once* instead using `expand.grid`.

Notes:

- Your expected output cycles the right-most columns first, whereas `expand.grid` cycles the left-most columns first. *The difference is completely aesthetic.* In order to more closely (but not exactly) match your expected output, I will change (mostly reverse) the order of arguments, then re-order the columns post-`expand.grid` (with `[,6:1]`). If this bothers you, order the columns the way you want, *it changes nothing in the subsequent calculations*.
- I'm not sure if you are intending to have all permutations of each `type` with each `price` (nine permutations), or if those two variables are paired (so `BBB` will only be `0.7`). If you mean the former, then we'll start with

  ```r
  eg <- expand.grid(Month = Month, Quantity = Quantity,
                    fixed_cost2 = fixed_cost, fixed_cost1 = fixed_cost1,
                    price = price, type = type)[,6:1]
  head(eg); tail(eg, 2)
  #   type price fixed_cost1 fixed_cost2 Quantity Month
  # 1  AAA   0.5         500         200      400     1
  # 2  AAA   0.5         500         200      400     2
  # 3  AAA   0.5         500         200      400     3
  # 4  AAA   0.5         500         200      700     1
  # 5  AAA   0.5         500         200      700     2
  # 6  AAA   0.5         500         200      700     3
  #    type price fixed_cost1 fixed_cost2 Quantity Month
  # 53  CCC   0.2         500         200      700     2
  # 54  CCC   0.2         500         200      700     3
  nrow(eg)
  # [1] 54
  ```

  However, if `BBB` is always `0.7`, then we need to change that slightly:

  ```r
  eg <- expand.grid(Month = Month, Quantity = Quantity,
                    fixed_cost2 = fixed_cost, fixed_cost1 = fixed_cost1,
                    tprow = seq_len(nrow(typeprice)))[,5:1]
  eg <- cbind(typeprice[eg$tprow,], eg[,-1])
  head(eg,3); tail(eg,2)
  #     type price fixed_cost1 fixed_cost2 Quantity Month
  # 1    AAA   0.5         500         200      400     1
  # 1.1  AAA   0.5         500         200      400     2
  # 1.2  AAA   0.5         500         200      400     3
  #     type price fixed_cost1 fixed_cost2 Quantity Month
  # 3.4  CCC   0.2         500         200      700     2
  # 3.5  CCC   0.2         500         200      700     3
  nrow(eg)
  # [1] 18
  ```

Use whichever of the `eg`s makes sense to you. I'll infer the second for now.

From here, it seems like a simple `transform` (or `dplyr::mutate` if you prefer):

```r
transform(eg, Total_Cost = (price * Quantity + fixed_cost1 + fixed_cost2) * Month)
#     type price fixed_cost1 fixed_cost2 Quantity Month Total_Cost
# 1    AAA   0.5         500         200      400     1        900
# 1.1  AAA   0.5         500         200      400     2       1800
# 1.2  AAA   0.5         500         200      400     3       2700
# 1.3  AAA   0.5         500         200      700     1       1050
# 1.4  AAA   0.5         500         200      700     2       2100
# 1.5  AAA   0.5         500         200      700     3       3150
# 2    BBB   0.7         500         200      400     1        980
# 2.1  BBB   0.7         500         200      400     2       1960
# 2.2  BBB   0.7         500         200      400     3       2940
# 2.3  BBB   0.7         500         200      700     1       1190
# 2.4  BBB   0.7         500         200      700     2       2380
# 2.5  BBB   0.7         500         200      700     3       3570
# 3    CCC   0.2         500         200      400     1        780
# 3.1  CCC   0.2         500         200      400     2       1560
# 3.2  CCC   0.2         500         200      400     3       2340
# 3.3  CCC   0.2         500         200      700     1        840
# 3.4  CCC   0.2         500         200      700     2       1680
# 3.5  CCC   0.2         500         200      700     3       2520
```

Comment: I used the first option and worked but for every type, it returned as permutations the prices also. As you correctly said each type "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" has its own price. It is exactly what you did like the final output. I cannot understand this a lot `tprow = seq_len(nrow(typeprice)))[,5:1]` @r2evans